What permissions are required for token to access GitHub private repositories
What permissions does a token need to access the raw content of a file in a github private repository via raw.githubusercontent.com?
Why is it that I have almost all permissions configured for a certain token, but using the url
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvhetd/verbose-memory/main/%E6%88%AA%E5%B1%8F2024-03-23%2020.15.03.png?token=ghp_ nwDhQycR1G5IkY**************"
still returns 404 when accessed, but is accessible using the auto-generated user temporary token.
I changed many token permissions and tried the github API, however it didn't work.
I just want to be able to successfully access the files in the repository without logging in, using the https url and a properly configured token.
